# How can I redirect all PDF files with file names that don't start with "public" to the home page?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress

I would like to disable direct access to all PDF files except those with a `public-` prefix on the beginning on the file name (e.g., `public-samplepdf.pdf`) so they can be viewed in public.  I'd like to redirect all other PDF files to my home page.

Here is .htaccess code that I have tried, but it isn't working.  What should I be doing instead?

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?public-(.*) /redirect-url/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when someone requests a file that doesn't have the `public-` prefix in the name, go to a `404` not found error page? Have you thought about adding password protection instead for files that shouldn't be available to the public? In other words, why have files on a server if you don't want to serve them?

Comment: i would like to redirect all pdf file that doesn't have public prefix

Comment: Again, where do you want them redirected to?

Comment: Some of file are public but theirs a files cannot be access. but when you logged in all file are accessable now

Comment: i want to redirect them to home page of my site

Comment: the redirection i already done but the exclusion of public file still not. RewriteRule ^(.+/)?public-(.*) /redirect-url/ [R=301,L] this code all public file are redirecting to my home page now, but i want to exclude all public file

Comment: To be clear, you want all files _not_ matching `public-` at the beginning to redirect to your root domain?

Comment: yes, all pdf file not matching public-.pdf will redirect to my root domain.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.+/)?public-(.*) /redirect-url/ [R=301,L]
> ```

This would seem to do the opposite (sort of) of what you are trying to do. It redirects any URL that *contains* the string "public-". It needs to match any URL that does *not* start "public-" in the last path segment and also ends with `.pdf`.

Also, this should not be a 301 (permanent) redirect, otherwise, users who have previously visited these URLs and been redirected will find it hard to visit the URL when they are authorised to do so (but see note below<sup>**[*1]**</sup>).

You can *negate* regular expressions in mod_rewrite simply by prefixing them with `!`. So `!foo` would match any URL that does not contain "foo".

Try the following instead, to redirect all non-public `.pdf` files to the home page:

```
RewriteRule !^(.+/)?public-[\w-]\.pdf$ / [R,L]
```

This unconditionally redirects every URL that does not match the given pattern. The character class `[\w-]` matches the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` and `-`. So, only alphanumeric characters plus underscore and hyphen are permitted in your PDF filenames.

If it should only redirect requests that would map to an actual file then you need an additional condition (if you are placing these directives at the top of the file). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule !^(.+/)?public-[\w-]\.pdf$ / [R,L]
```

Or, place these directives *after* the WordPress front-controller.

> Some of file are public but theirs a files cannot be access. **but when you logged in all file are accessable**

<sup>**[*1]**</sup> Although I don't know how you were hoping to implement that when you are *unconditionally* redirecting all these requests in `.htaccess`?

---

Bit of an aside, but ... you shouldn't normally "block" requests by redirecting to the homepage. And nor would you use mod_rewrite to block access to specific files on the filesystem. mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` primarily deals with URLs, not filesystem paths.

To specifically *block* access to `.pdf` files (ie. serve a 403 Forbidden), but allow `public-` `.pdf` files then you would use mod_authz_core (Apache 2.4+) inside a `<FilesMatch>` container. For example:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!public-).+\.pdf$">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

The above regex uses a negative lookahead to match all `.pdf` files that do not start with "public-".

Comment: Good breakdown and explanation.